# Как можно запустить скрипт по нажатию кнопки?

Tags: python, клавиатура

Есть скрипт пайтон, и нужна чтобы после запуска py фаила, скрипт запускался и ставился на паузу и останавливался при нажатии клавиши клавиатуры ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import keyboard

def main():
    while True:
        if keyboard.is_pressed('r'):
            break
        print("Hello Codex!")

main()
```